# Plus de temps vs plus longtemps

Tags: adverbes

Is there any difference of meaning between "plus de temps" and "plus longtemps" ? Are both equally usual? Example:

- La pluie durera plus de temps que prévu.
- La pluie durera plus longtemps que prévu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples can be and are used without any significant difference in meaning although in theory, *plus longtemps* is longer than *plus de temps*.

There are a few cases where *plus longtemps* is not idiomatic or unused :

> J'ai besoin de plus de temps.
>
> *J'ai besoin de plus longtemps.